# Just got back into bitcoin but theres almost no way for me to use my bitcoins, please help!

Tags: wallet-recovery

I recently got back into bitcoin after 3 years and I want access to my wallet I saved on my HardDisk a while back. It seems the wallet manager I used (multibit wallet) is out of date. However NO other software seems to be able to read my wallet so I am stuck using it. I cannot send bitcoins to anyone because it sends and is pending for days (3 days at this point).

I watched a youtube video that described how to transfer multibit wallet to electrum but that video did not help and the commments section was closed (I suspect because it just does not work).

What can I do? I cannot use anything else but an old multibit software but the software does not send bitcoins correctly...
Am I just out all of the money I invested in this?

P.S. I tried sending the bitcoins to coinbase because that website is still up but they end up being pending for days and coinbase is not getting back to me.

Answer (score 1):

There must be a solution so don't be too worried. According to the [multibit blog](https://multibit.org/blog/2017/07/26/multibit-shutdown.html), an attempt to move it to Electrum is valid.

> If you are having problems logging into Multibit, we created a utility to export the keys from your Multibit wallet file. Instructions for how install and use it are at https://github.com/Multibit-Legacy/read-multibit-wallet-file

The [github repo](https://github.com/Multibit-Legacy/read-multibit-wallet-file) provides a process of getting the key.

1. Install node version 6 or higher. You can get it from https://nodejs.org/en/download/.
2. Open a command prompt and install this utility: `npm install -g mbexport`
3. `mbexport <path-to-wallet-file>`

`<path-to-wallet-file>` is on the README file of the repo.

If you can provide information about OS you're using and about software class (Multibit classic or MultibitHD), you'll probably hear the more detailed answers.

Hope you'll find a way.

Comment: I installed node 8.9.3 and ran npm install -g mbexport on my command prompt as administrator. I have multibitclassic. Results from command prompt are:                                                                                              npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno EACCES
npm ERR! FetchError: request to https://registry.npmjs.org/mbexport failed, reason: connect EACCES 151.101.40.162:443                                                                     And much more code that will not fit in a comment. Thanks for the response!